# Detecting changes in interrelated properties in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have two public properties in my **component.ts**:

```
public hierarchicalData: object[] = [];
// Mapping TreeView fields property with data source properties
public field: Object = { dataSource: this.hierarchicalData, id: 'id', text: 'name', child: 'subChild' };
```

These two properties are used to get data in **Syncfusion.Angular.TreeView**.

I have the following **component.html**:

```
<div class="control_wrapper">
    <ejs-treeview id="default" [fields]='field'></ejs-treeview>
</div>
```

I use the following function to fill data:

```
    readHierarchicalData(e: any): void {
        this.hierarchicalData = [
        {
             id: '01', name: 'Asset', expanded: true,
             subChild: [
             {
                 id: '01-01', name: 'Motor',
                 subChild: [
                     { id: '01-01-01', name: 'Shaft' },
                  ]
               },
            }
        ];
    }
```

This function is triggered by a button click event. The problem is that `<ejs-treeview id="default" [fields]='field'></ejs-treeview>` cannot get new data by running `readHierarchicalData()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the change detection of `ejs-treeview` is `OnPush`, so it means you need to redefine your `fields` property to make it work.

```
eadHierarchicalData(e: any): void {
        this.hierarchicalData = [
        {
             id: '01', name: 'Asset', expanded: true,
             subChild: [
             {
                 id: '01-01', name: 'Motor',
                 subChild: [
                     { id: '01-01-01', name: 'Shaft' },
                  ]
               },
            }
        ];

       this.field = {...this.field, dataSource: this.hierarchicalData };
    }
```